# Oracle database change notification with ODP.NET doesn't work

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I'm complete newbie to Oracle DB trying to enable DB change notifications.

```
private void RegisterNotification()
    {
        const string connstring = "Data Source=ORA_DB;User Id=USER;Password=pass;";
        try
        {
            var connObj = new OracleConnection(connstring);
            connObj.Open();
            var cmdObj = connObj.CreateCommand();
            cmdObj.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
            var dep = new OracleDependency(cmdObj);
            dep.QueryBasedNotification = false;
            dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnNotificationReceived);
            cmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connObj.Close();
            connObj.Dispose();
            connObj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

public static void OnNotificationReceived(object src, OracleNotificationEventArgs arg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Table has changed!");
    }
```

I've executed "GRANT CHANGE NOTIFICATION TO USER;" but nothing happens when I change the table data neither manually nor programmatically. Query-based notifications also don't work. I suppose I miss something in Oracle configuration.

I have Oracle 11.2 standard edition.

Answer (score 1):

The `CHANGE NOTIFICATION` permission is not on the features of the Standard Edition for latest versions :
[Licensing information](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87)

> **Oracle TimesTen Application-Tier Database Cache :**
>
> Data access using PL/SQL, JDBC, ODBC, ttClasses, OCI, and Pro*C/C++
>
> **interfaces Transaction Log API (XLA) for change notification**
>
> Multi-node Cache Grid
>
> ...

SE2 : N

EE : Y (extra-cost option)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute your soft under admin permission and as console application. when we used to deal with it we faced with the same stuff. we hadn't managed to use it in webservices.