# How can I use SignalR with angularJS and Oracle using DbChangeNotification

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, signalr

I am trying to use SignalR with Oracle and AngularJS.

I want to notify when insert/update happens in database.

I have done it with MS SQL Server.
But with oracle, problem is I need to know to implement **DB Change Notification** Properly with oracle.
**OracleDependency** not firing events

I have tried like this but could not succeed.

http://haneefputtur.com/signalr-oracle-db-change-notification-part-2-2.html

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the underlying database is not supporting the notification service.
Check this
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336931/oracle-database-change-notification-with-odp-net-doesnt-work) for more info